# what dose "two consistent strata" mean

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following sentence is cited from TOEFL reading material:

> While rock between two consistent strata might in one place be shale and in another sandstone, the fossils in that shale or sandstone were always the same.

I don't quite know what the sentence means. Maybe because I don't know the exact meaning of "consistent". Can you explain the sentence to me?

Comment: This question seems to be copy and pasted from a wordReference post of 2013 https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/consistent.2752439/ Why?

Comment: i want a better answer to the question

Comment: The context is the field of geology, and it is quite likely that **consistent** has some precise and specific meaning within that field. Aside from that, what about the dictionary definition of the word is confusing to you?